# Mysql: Obtener calificacion de alumno en cada periodo

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

estoy intentando obtener las calificaciones de un determinado alumno de una materia x por cada periodo pero no logro obtenerlo.

A modo de ejemplo, necesito obtener esta estructura, en el caso en que no haya una nota registrada para un determinado periodo que aparezca null.

[image: consulta.png]

Intente con el siguiente código:

```
select * from periodos p 
left join calificaciones c on p.PeriodoID = c.PeriodoID 
where c.AlumnoID = 1 and c.AsignaturaID = 1 ;
```

¿Como podria lograrlo? Desde ya muchas gracias.

**PD: El motor es MariaDB 10.3**

La tabla Periodos:

[image: periodos.png]

La tabla calificaciones:

[image: Captura-de-pantalla-de-2021-10-11-18-04-44.png]

Edicion: Se agrega ejemplo minimo y verificable

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `periodos` (
  `PeriodoID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Descripcion` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FechaInicio` date NOT NULL,
  `FechaFin` date NOT NULL,
  `UnidadAdministrativaID` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PeriodoID`)
);

INSERT INTO periodos
(PeriodoID, Descripcion, FechaInicio, FechaFin, UnidadAdministrativaID)
VALUES(3, 'Talleres Intensivos Diciembre', '2021-03-01', '2021-12-23', 1);
INSERT INTO periodos
(PeriodoID, Descripcion, FechaInicio, FechaFin, UnidadAdministrativaID)
VALUES(4, 'Talleres Intensivos Febrero', '2021-03-17', '2021-12-24', 1);
INSERT INTO periodos
(PeriodoID, Descripcion, FechaInicio, FechaFin, UnidadAdministrativaID)
VALUES(7, 'Primer cuatrimestre', '2021-03-17', '2021-03-24', 1);
INSERT INTO periodos
(PeriodoID, Descripcion, FechaInicio, FechaFin, UnidadAdministrativaID)
VALUES(8, 'Segundo cuatrimestre', '2021-03-17', '2021-03-17', 1);
INSERT INTO periodos
(PeriodoID, Descripcion, FechaInicio, FechaFin, UnidadAdministrativaID)
VALUES(9, 'Evaluación final', '2021-03-17', '2021-03-17', 1);
```

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `periodos` (
  `PeriodoID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Descripcion` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FechaInicio` date NOT NULL,
  `FechaFin` date NOT NULL,
  `UnidadAdministrativaID` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PeriodoID`)
);

INSERT INTO periodos
(PeriodoID, Descripcion, FechaInicio, FechaFin, UnidadAdministrativaID)
VALUES(3, 'Talleres Intensivos Diciembre', '2021-03-01', '2021-12-23', 1);
INSERT INTO periodos
(PeriodoID, Descripcion, FechaInicio, FechaFin, UnidadAdministrativaID)
VALUES(4, 'Talleres Intensivos Febrero', '2021-03-17', '2021-12-24', 1);
INSERT INTO periodos
(PeriodoID, Descripcion, FechaInicio, FechaFin, UnidadAdministrativaID)
VALUES(7, 'Primer cuatrimestre', '2021-03-17', '2021-03-24', 1);
INSERT INTO periodos
(PeriodoID, Descripcion, FechaInicio, FechaFin, UnidadAdministrativaID)
VALUES(8, 'Segundo cuatrimestre', '2021-03-17', '2021-03-17', 1);
INSERT INTO periodos
(PeriodoID, Descripcion, FechaInicio, FechaFin, UnidadAdministrativaID)
VALUES(9, 'Evaluación final', '2021-03-17', '2021-03-17', 1);

CREATE TABLE `calificaciones` (
  `NotaID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AsignaturaID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FechaCarga` datetime NOT NULL,
  `AlumnoID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PeriodoID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'id del periodo de evaluacion, por ejemplo: 1 cuatrimestre, 2 cuatrimestre, tallers de marzo, etc.',
  `Calificacion` varchar(30) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nota del alumno',
  `UnidadEducativaID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NivelEnsenanzaID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CicloID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ID de ciclo lectivo',
  `AnioCicloID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Id del año/curso. Por ejemplo, 1885 pertenece a Segundo 1 Mañana de Ntra Sra del Rosario',
  `AnioCicloLectivo` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Año lectivo, por ejemplo, 2020,2021, etc..',
  PRIMARY KEY (`NotaID`),
  KEY `calificaciones_FK` (`PeriodoID`),
  CONSTRAINT `calificaciones_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`PeriodoID`) REFERENCES `periodos` (`PeriodoID`)
);

INSERT INTO calificaciones
(NotaID, AsignaturaID, FechaCarga, AlumnoID, PeriodoID, Calificacion, UnidadEducativaID, NivelEnsenanzaID, CicloID, AnioCicloID, AnioCicloLectivo)
VALUES(261, 1, '2021-10-10 16:35:43.000', 1, 3, '10', 4, 27, 387, 1885, '2020');
INSERT INTO calificaciones
(NotaID, AsignaturaID, FechaCarga, AlumnoID, PeriodoID, Calificacion, UnidadEducativaID, NivelEnsenanzaID, CicloID, AnioCicloID, AnioCicloLectivo)
VALUES(262, 1, '2021-10-10 16:35:43.000', 2, 3, '5.5', 4, 27, 387, 1885, '2020');
INSERT INTO calificaciones
(NotaID, AsignaturaID, FechaCarga, AlumnoID, PeriodoID, Calificacion, UnidadEducativaID, NivelEnsenanzaID, CicloID, AnioCicloID, AnioCicloLectivo)
VALUES(263, 1, '2021-10-10 16:35:43.000', 3, 3, '4.3', 4, 27, 387, 1885, '2020');
INSERT INTO calificaciones
(NotaID, AsignaturaID, FechaCarga, AlumnoID, PeriodoID, Calificacion, UnidadEducativaID, NivelEnsenanzaID, CicloID, AnioCicloID, AnioCicloLectivo)
VALUES(264, 2, '2021-10-10 16:41:04.000', 1, 3, 'Regular', 4, 27, 387, 1885, '2020');
INSERT INTO calificaciones
(NotaID, AsignaturaID, FechaCarga, AlumnoID, PeriodoID, Calificacion, UnidadEducativaID, NivelEnsenanzaID, CicloID, AnioCicloID, AnioCicloLectivo)
VALUES(265, 2, '2021-10-10 16:41:04.000', 2, 3, 'Muy bueno', 4, 27, 387, 1885, '2020');
INSERT INTO calificaciones
(NotaID, AsignaturaID, FechaCarga, AlumnoID, PeriodoID, Calificacion, UnidadEducativaID, NivelEnsenanzaID, CicloID, AnioCicloID, AnioCicloLectivo)
VALUES(266, 2, '2021-10-10 16:41:04.000', 3, 3, 'Bueno', 4, 27, 387, 1885, '2020');
INSERT INTO calificaciones
(NotaID, AsignaturaID, FechaCarga, AlumnoID, PeriodoID, Calificacion, UnidadEducativaID, NivelEnsenanzaID, CicloID, AnioCicloID, AnioCicloLectivo)
VALUES(279, 3, '2021-10-10 18:26:35.000', 1, 3, 'Bueno', 4, 27, 387, 1885, '2020');
INSERT INTO calificaciones
(NotaID, AsignaturaID, FechaCarga, AlumnoID, PeriodoID, Calificacion, UnidadEducativaID, NivelEnsenanzaID, CicloID, AnioCicloID, AnioCicloLectivo)
VALUES(280, 3, '2021-10-10 18:26:35.000', 2, 3, 'Bueno', 4, 27, 387, 1885, '2020');
INSERT INTO calificaciones
(NotaID, AsignaturaID, FechaCarga, AlumnoID, PeriodoID, Calificacion, UnidadEducativaID, NivelEnsenanzaID, CicloID, AnioCicloID, AnioCicloLectivo)
VALUES(281, 3, '2021-10-10 18:26:35.000', 3, 3, 'Bueno', 4, 27, 387, 1885, '2020');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM periodos;
```

| PeriodoID | Descripcion | FechaInicio | FechaFin | UnidadAdministrativaID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Talleres Intensivos Diciembre | 2021-03-01 | 2021-12-23 | 1 |
| 4 | Talleres Intensivos Febrero | 2021-03-17 | 2021-12-24 | 1 |
| 7 | Primer cuatrimestre | 2021-03-17 | 2021-03-24 | 1 |
| 8 | Segundo cuatrimestre | 2021-03-17 | 2021-03-17 | 1 |
| 9 | Evaluación final | 2021-03-17 | 2021-03-17 | 1 |

---

**Query #2**

```
select * from calificaciones;
```

| NotaID | AsignaturaID | FechaCarga | AlumnoID | PeriodoID | Calificacion | UnidadEducativaID | NivelEnsenanzaID | CicloID | AnioCicloID | AnioCicloLectivo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 261 | 1 | 2021-10-10 16:35:43 | 1 | 3 | 10 | 4 | 27 | 387 | 1885 | 2020 |
| 262 | 1 | 2021-10-10 16:35:43 | 2 | 3 | 5.5 | 4 | 27 | 387 | 1885 | 2020 |
| 263 | 1 | 2021-10-10 16:35:43 | 3 | 3 | 4.3 | 4 | 27 | 387 | 1885 | 2020 |
| 264 | 2 | 2021-10-10 16:41:04 | 1 | 3 | Regular | 4 | 27 | 387 | 1885 | 2020 |
| 265 | 2 | 2021-10-10 16:41:04 | 2 | 3 | Muy bueno | 4 | 27 | 387 | 1885 | 2020 |
| 266 | 2 | 2021-10-10 16:41:04 | 3 | 3 | Bueno | 4 | 27 | 387 | 1885 | 2020 |
| 279 | 3 | 2021-10-10 18:26:35 | 1 | 3 | Bueno | 4 | 27 | 387 | 1885 | 2020 |
| 280 | 3 | 2021-10-10 18:26:35 | 2 | 3 | Bueno | 4 | 27 | 387 | 1885 | 2020 |
| 281 | 3 | 2021-10-10 18:26:35 | 3 | 3 | Bueno | 4 | 27 | 387 | 1885 | 2020 |

---

**Query #3**

```
select * from periodos p 
left join calificaciones c on p.PeriodoID = c.PeriodoID 
where c.AlumnoID = 1 and c.AsignaturaID = 1 ;
```

| PeriodoID | Descripcion | FechaInicio | FechaFin | UnidadAdministrativaID | NotaID | AsignaturaID | FechaCarga | AlumnoID | PeriodoID | Calificacion | UnidadEducativaID | NivelEnsenanzaID | CicloID | AnioCicloID | AnioCicloLectivo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Talleres Intensivos Diciembre | 2021-03-01 | 2021-12-23 | 1 | 261 | 1 | 2021-10-10 16:35:43 | 1 | 3 | 10 | 4 | 27 | 387 | 1885 | 2020 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: La pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Qué arroja la consulta que tienes hasta ahora? ¿Se necesita sumar? Convendría que agregues un pequeño set de datos con un ejemplo mínimo y verificable. Esto ayudará mucho más que las imágenes. Si uno quisiera hacer pruebas tendría que crear todo desde cero y agregarle datos.

Comment: Tienes razon @A.Cedano , ahora agrego el resultado. ¿Como agregaria el set de datos?

Comment: Hay sitios en los cuales puedes crear un set de datos completo, [por ejemplo este](https://www.db-fiddle.com/). Así los usuarios que vayan a responder pueden analizar/probar el código y obtendrás respuestas de forma más rápida y más precisa. Lo único que tienes que hacer es agregar los `CREATE TABLE` y algunos `INSERT` con unas pocas filas. Eso es lo que se conoce como *ejemplo mínimo y verificable*. Para obtener tus `CREATE TABLE` sólo tienes que ejecutar `SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla`  en tu SGBD.